# Web application running on both Oracle and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, clob, longtext

I have a web application that works on both Oracle and MySQL Databases, my problem is that I want to create a column in the database that has a `LONGTEXT` type in MySQL and `CLOB` in Oracle, how can I achieve that using Hibernate? Here is my code:

```
@Column(name = "BigText" , nullable = false)
public String getBigText() {
    return bigText;
}
```

I tried using: `columnDefinition="LONGTEXT"`, it is working under MySQL but not Oracle. What else can I do?

Comment: compare datatypes in oracle and mysql...you take relavant datatype

Comment: what? I am sorry I didn't understand what you said. @sureshmanda

Answer (score 0):

see the below link

[defference between oracle and mysql datatype](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/win.920/a97249/ch3.htm)

if(databasename.equals("oracle"){
  use here entity for oracle datatype used
}else if(databasename.equals("mysql"){
 use here entity for mysqldatatype used
}

Comment: Have you even read my question? this should not be an answer BTW. I know the differences between the two databases and data types (I have been working on both databases for 2 years.. Dah!!)

Comment: you get the database name and write the if condition for oracle and mysql use different entity based on database

Comment: see the answer...understand

Comment: I can't create different entities for my table, I have to use ONE entity.

Comment: i phase this type of problem with three databases.so i create three  entities.and used in dao with database name

Comment: Here is the thing, my application creates the database tables on startup (hibernate does that). So I need to add the annotation NOT create other entities for every database.